# Why is WHERE being used to JOIN the same table

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, subquery, where-clause

I have been taking a class with Coursera. There is a query that is incorporating a subquery in the `SELECT` clause. I understand about 90% of the query; however, I cannot figure out why we need to use `WHERE` in the subquery. The `WHERE` is acting like the `JOIN ON`. I don't know why a `JOIN ON` would be needed.

```
SELECT
    starttime,
    stoptime,
    start_station_id,
    tripduration,
    (SELECT ROUND(AVG(tripduration), 2) 
     FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
     WHERE start_station_id = outer_trips.start_station_id) AS avg_duration_for_stations,
     ROUND (tripduration - (SELECT AVG(tripduration) 
                            FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
                            WHERE start_station_id = outer_trips.start_station_id), 2)
FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` AS outer_trips
```

I tried to eliminate the `WHERE` because it is used as a filter. I could not understand why it was functioning as a JOIN ON. I was expecting a subquery that would create two additional columns without the lengthy steps of adding `WHERE`.

Why is `WHERE` being used to `JOIN` the same table?

Comment: It's a _correlated subquery_. (Similar to a LEFT JOIN.)

Comment: On a side note: you could have just used window functions instead of subqueries. Eg `ROUND(AVG(tripduration) OVER (PARTITION BY start_station_id), 2)`

Comment: This is extremely unclear. What do 'acting like JOIN ON' & 'functioning as a JOIN ON' mean? What do you mean, 'lengthy steps of adding WHERE'? What is the problem? Why is 'WHERE is used as a filter' a justification to 'eliminate the where'? Etc. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. What exactly is your 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question? Please don't rephrase it several times slightly differently in the form of what you don't understand or expect. Just ask 1 clear question. Please don't put something only in the title.

Comment: [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: There has been no impatience or impoliteness in responses & no reason to think there has been. There has been & still is extreme unclearness in the question post. (What does "being used to JOIN" mean considering there is no JOIN?) Your familiarity to SQL was edited out because it is irrelevant to whatever technical question  is asked or its answers--as with other social or meta commentary in posts. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.

Comment: Clearly your question(s) when clear will be faqs. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: [Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2577174/3404097) etc etc

Comment: Clearly for every row from the outer FROM each subquery WHERE keeps only the rows from its FROM base table WHERE start_station_id = outer_trips.start_station_id. Because that's how FROM, WHERE & SELECT are defined to act. But you need to pin down the 1st spot where an expression returns what you don't expect or you are expecting us to walk through the code saying what the manual says the language returns when you are not willing to & with no details on what you do or don't understand or misunderstand.

Answer (score 0):

the WHERE clause in the subquery  actually filters the rows from the

```
bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
```

where the start_station_id matches the start_station_id of the current row being processed.

In the outer query to ensure that the average trip duration calculated in the subquery is specific to the start or each individual trip in the outer query.

the reason for the need to use WHERE in the subquery is because it filters the rows from the citibike_trips table so as to calculate the average trip duration , i think its used to target trips starting at the same stations the current row in the outer query. if you remove the where filtering it would return the average trip duration for all trips not just theones starting at the same station , which changes the intended behaviour of the query.

Comment: Please use standard spelling & punctuation.